# How to set table's collation to utf8_persian_ci while creating them by PDO

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8, pdo, collation

I want to create several tables in Mysql database by PDO.

I use this code :

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.'; dbname='.$db , $username, $password);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS d1
(
  Course_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  course_start INT(5) NOT NULL,
  course_row INT(22) NOT NULL,
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
)";
$sq = $db->query($sql);
```

but I have a big problem: The tables collation must be `utf8_persian_ci` or  `utf8_bin`.
How can I set the collation of tables while they are being creating?

And I have database where I want to change its collation to `utf8_persian_ci` or `utf8_bin` too.
what shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have solved my collation problems supporting Hungarian characters:

```
use szatmarihidegyesulet;
ALTER DATABASE szatmarihidegyesulet CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE admin_users CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE article_items CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE articles CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE contacts CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE content_groups CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE content_types CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE galleries CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE gallery_materials CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE materials CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE sources CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE tags CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

You can do the same but for your own tables. I do not know how you set this when you create a table, but you can alter it all the same.